# Why is asset conversion limited to 6 hops?

Tags: stellar-core

Is there a technical reason asset conversion in the builtin [distributed exchange](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/exchange.html) is limited to 6 hops?  Or is it because of the [six degrees of separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_degrees_of_separation) principle?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that 6 hops constant is just a performance limitation as the complexity of path finding grows with each additional hop. Even 6 hops is an overkill in most situations because almost all path payment operations can be executed in 1 (direct path) or 2 (via XLM) hops.